# Extract Key Value Pair from Object in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to extract the key value pairs from the `order` object and i want it to be combined to formData

**Code**

```
  const formData = {
      avatar: this.image,
      documents: this.order.documents,
      Object.entries(orders)
   };
```

**Expected Output**

```
avatar: 'http://images',
document: 'http://document',
Name: 'John Doe',
Food: 'Banana'
```

**Object**

```
orders: {
  'Name': 'John Doe',
  'Food': 'Banana'
}
```

Comment: `Object.entries(orders)`

Comment: What is the end result expected to look like?

Comment: @Ifaruki. Pls check my edited question

Comment: @GuyIncognito. Pls check my edited question

Comment: Try it out to find out. Also, you can just use orders by itself, without doing anything to it to get the format you want.

Comment: are you asking how to merge `orders` into the `formData` object?

Comment: Does this answer your question?  [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/171251)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, you need the spread operator

```
const formData = {
      avatar: this.image,
      documents: this.order.documents,
      ...orders
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

use the spead operator:

```js
const formData = {
  avatar: this.image,
  documents: this.order.documents,
  ...orders
};
```